# How to go full screen in a terminal on PocketC.H.I.P.?

Tags: terminal, fullscreen, ntc-pocketchip, xfce4-terminal

How can I get rid of the menu bar at the top of the terminal app on a PocketC.H.I.P? It would be nice to hide the scrollbar as well.

Is it even possible to disable the scroll bar and the menu bar in `vala-terminal` which is the default terminal on the PokcetCHIP? Is it possible in `xfce4-terminal`?

---

[image: The menu bar is at the top and the scrollbar is on the right.]

<sup>*The menu bar is at the top and the scrollbar is on the right.*</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are 2 terminals available on the PocketC.H.I.P. out of the box:

- `vala-terminal`
- `xfce4-terminal`

### `vala-terminal`

I've read the manual and it looks like this emulator doesn't provide an option to disable bars.

### `xfce4-terminal`

I was able to disable the menu bar after tinkering with the `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` file.

I wasn't able to disable the scroll bar though. According to the Internet, it cannot be easily achieved.

### New hope: the `st` terminal emulator

I decided to install a lightwieght terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxft-dev libxext-dev
git clone git://git.suckless.org/st
cd st
sudo make clean install
```

And then I edited my the menu config file (`/usr/share/pocket-home/config.json`) to make the terminal icon launch `st`:

```
{
  "defaultPage" : "Apps",
  "pages": [
    {
      "name": "Apps",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Terminal",
          "icon": "appIcons/terminal.png",
          "shell": "st"
        },
      (...)
```

And now I can enjoy my uncluttered terminal in my PocketC.H.I.P.

Comment: st works a treat.  However, changing the json file doesn't seem to make the icon click start st.  Strange...

Comment: Actually, I think I know why.  I use PocketDesk.